# Positioning with tikz: adding things like on a blackboard

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

When creating a presentation that evolves as if the maths teacher is writing on a classical blackboard some problems occur.
In the MWE the first line moves up when removing the "%" for activating the last line.

Is there a practical way of designing such presentations? I thought of relative coordinates but did not succeed. Best would be fixing the headline and then add the other stuff subsequently.
(In my opintion designing the complete final state by e. g. align environments or so is not practical. So I came to the idea of using tikz.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\onslide<1->{\node at (5,4) {Headline: Topic of the day};}
\onslide<2->{\node at (1,1) {$5a=5b$};}
\onslide<3->{\node at (1,0) {$a=b$};}
\onslide<4->{\node at (5,0.5) {Here we have done something};}
%\node at (1,-2) {$x=y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is precisely the purpose of the `overlay-beamer-styles` library to avoid such jumps. Instead of `\onslide` use the pgf keys `visible on`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}%[t] %<- is in general better IMHO
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[visible on=<1->] at (5,4) {Headline: Topic of the day};
\node[visible on=<2->] at (1,1) {$5a=5b$};
\node[visible on=<3->] at (1,0) {$a=b$};
\node[visible on=<4->] at (5,0.5) {Here we have done something};
%\node at (1,-2) {$x=y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, I also recommend using the `[t]` option for the frames. It top-aligns the content, so if you add something below with `\pause`, say, there won't be jumps.

Comment: Perfect. Additionally I will set the headline node at (...,0) and everything else with negative y values.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem even using a fixed bounding box.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0,2); %<- bounding box
\onslide<1->{\node at (5,4) {Headline: Topic of the day};}
\onslide<2->{\node at (1,1) {$5a=5b$};}
\onslide<3->{\node at (1,0) {$a=b$};}
\onslide<4->{\node at (5,0.5) {Here we have done something};}
\node at (1,-2) {$x=y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```